# Does Google Datastore have a provisioned capacity system like DynamoDB?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, amazon-dynamodb

I have looked around quite a bit for any information on how Google Datastore scales up and whether you have to pre-order capacity like with DynamoDB.

I couldn't find a shred of info since they changed up their pricing model in March 2016.

Is Datastore a noSQL that you can throw anything at it and it just scales (without you thinking about hidden partitions)?

I looked on this [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) page but all it says is a fixed flat fee per read & write (no mention of a provisioned capacity system where you CAN get throttled if you go over your queries/sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as pre-ordering capacity with the Google datastore.

But while the datastore itself is highly scalable you need to take care of scalability on your app side as well. From [Avoiding datastore contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention):

> App Engine's datastore is a powerful distributed data storage service
>   built on top of the high-performance database management system known
>   as Bigtable. Although the datastore is built to scale, you must take
>   care when designing your data models to avoid the prospect of
>   contention as your application grows.
>
> ...
>
> App Engine is a great "engine" for building highly scalable web
>   applications backed by a world-class infrastructure, but it's your
>   responsibility to use the tools provided as effectively and
>   efficiently as possible. A large part of this is designing your data
>   model to leverage the [core strengths](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/whyappengine) of App Engine's underlying
>   datastore and doing so early-on so you can reap the rewards as your
>   application's traffic skyrockets.

You don't need to worry about throttling, but you *might* want to worry about cost :) See [Datastore Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Datastore).

Comment: Thanks for the info! how would you compare it to dynamo's write/read performance - I just feel like there's a gotcha somehow especially that DataStore lets you set indexes per item, which is crazy flexible!

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ dynamo, but AFAIK it's not a Google-scale company which runs a ton of their own services (including the datastore) on top of the same BigTable. I'd be surprised if dynamo's performance would match datastore's *at scale*. The datastore's per-entity group max write rate of 1 batch per second  may appear limiting and the eventualy consistency may complicate things a bit but I understand they're necessary to achieve its great scalability.

Answer (score -1):

> Is Datastore a noSQL that you can throw anything at it and it just scales (without you thinking about hidden partitions)?

Yes.